# unable to write csv from array

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I read most of the discussions about my problem but I do not find a solution. 
So, I have a .csv file from which I read, extract all the content and populate a multidimensional array. That is the code I wrote to do that:

```
 if (($handle = fopen("dateRegion.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
 # Set the parent multidimensional array key to 0.
 $pr = 0;
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    # Count the total keys in the row.
    $count = count($data);
    # Populate the multidimensional array.
    for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
        $brim[$pr][$x] = $data[$x];
    }
 $pr++;
  }
fclose($handle);
```

}

After that, I extract the element I need and put it into another array. That array will be the content of the new .csv file.

This is the code:

```
      $parserCsv = array();
      $dip=1;
       do {
        $region = $brim[$dip][7];
        $sex = $brim[$dip][8];
        $frequency = $brim[$dip][9];
        $value = $brim[$dip][10];
        $parserCsv[] = array($region, $sex, $frequency, $value);
      $dip++;
       } while($dip <= 6336);
```

This is the "var_dump()" of the array:

```
Array(
[0] => Piemonte
[1] => maschi
[2] => 2005
[3] => 16.972)
```

etc.

I tried to put the content of the array $parserCsv using the method fputcsv(), with that script:

```
$fp = fopen('csvExtract.csv', 'w');
 foreach ($parserCsv as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields);
 }
fclose($fp);
```

but it did not work. The content of the file csvExtract.csv is blank. I do not understand my mistake, I tried other solution like create the array $parserCsv like:

```
 $parserCsv = array(
    array($region), array($sex), array($frequency), array($value));
```

and nothing change. Does anyone have some advise?

EDIT: Edited the code with the solution suggested by mkjasinski! The code is working now.
Thanks for all the replies.

Brus

Comment: Do you have write access to the directory?

Comment: Yes i have. I'm the owner of the server where the scripts are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (($handle = fopen("dateRegion.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    # Set the parent multidimensional array key to 0.
    $pr = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        # Count the total keys in the row.
        $count = count($data);
        # Populate the multidimensional array.
        for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
            $brim[$pr][$x] = $data[$x];
        }
        $pr++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

and this:

```
$parserCsv = array();
$dip=1;
do {
    $region = $brim[$dip][7];
    $sex = $brim[$dip][8];
    $frequency = $brim[$dip][9];
    $value = $brim[$dip][10];
    $parserCsv[] = array($region, $sex, $frequency, $value);
    $dip++;
} while($dip <= 6336);
```

and save:

```
$fp = fopen('csvExtract.csv', 'w');
foreach ($parserCsv as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

are you getting some errors?
Is the file open in some other software? (like MS Excel?)

Following code enters 4 records in CSV

```
$parserCsv = array(
   array('Piemonte'),
   array('maschi'),
   array(2005),
   array(16.972)
);

$fp = fopen('blah.csv', 'w');
foreach($parserCsv as $fields)
{
   fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Hi Ejay, thanks for the reply. No errors in the code you posted. I already tryed that way, and it works. I'm not understanding why if i give the array $parserCsv (with only the elements i need) to the fputcsv method, it doesn't work properly. Any Idea?

Comment: [fput_csv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) seconds argument to the function has got to be an array, you provide `String` in your first example.

Comment: extending the discussion to make it clear (for future reader)  `foreach ($parserCsv as $fields) {` inside `foreach` block, `$fields` is a `String` (in your original code)